# TSQL Subtracting ROW_NUMBER()

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, row, subtraction

I'm having trouble getting this to work. Its Paging centered on a certain row @Row offset by 2 and 5.

```
DECLARE @Row INT;
SET @Row = CONVERT(INT, (SELECT RowNumber FROM TopScores WHERE Name = 'Rafa'));

SELECT RowNumber, Name, HighScore
FROM TopScores
OFFSET (@Row-2) ROWS
FETCH NEXT 5 ROWS ONLY;
```

If I could somehow embed the local variable statement within the second and get rid of the variable, that would be preferred, but I can't get anything to work.

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
>   Incorrect syntax near '@Row'.
>
> Msg 153, Level 15, State 2, Line 7
>   Invalid usage of the option NEXT in the FETCH statement.

To add a bit more context, here's the view "TopScores"

```
CREATE VIEW TopScores AS 
   SELECT 
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY HighScore DESC) AS RowNumber, 
      Name, HighScore 
   FROM 
      [dbo].[LeaderBoards]
```

Comment: Wouldn't `@Row-2` instead of `2-@Row` solve the problem?

Comment: Silly me, but no that wasn't the problem. I put up the errors.

Comment: Yeah I'm with @alzaimar on this one. You really want to start at `@Row-2` and then fetch 8 rows (your 2 before, your row, your 5 after). Need to handle the edge case of negative offsets but aside from that you should be okay. If the problem is `OFFSET @Row-2` isn't accepted but `OFFSET @Row` is then just stick `-2` on your `SET @Row ...` line.

Comment: @ta.speot.is unfortunately that didn't work either, it really doesn't like having a variable with the OFFSET statement.

Comment: Well it should, I believe I've seen EF do it. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg699618(v=sql.110).aspx *The argument for the OFFSET clause can be an integer or expression that is greater than or equal to zero*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.
From the documentation: "•ORDER BY is mandatory to use OFFSET and FETCH clause."

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[RetrieveRelOffset]
    @LowerOffset INT,
    @UpperOffset INT,
    @Name NVARCHAR(10)
AS 
BEGIN
    --Stops the message that shows the count of the number of rows affected by a RSQL statement
    --or stored procedure from being returned as part of the result set.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @Row INT;
    SET @Row = CONVERT(INT, (SELECT RowNumber FROM TopScores WHERE Name = @Name)) - @LowerOffset;

    SELECT Name, HighScore
    FROM TopScores
    ORDER BY HighScore
    OFFSET @Row ROWS
    FETCH NEXT @UpperOffset ROWS ONLY;
END;
```

Comment: *Reasons unknown* [That's the syntax](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg699618(v=sql.110).aspx). How else is it supposed to know what the "first" and "last" rows are without some defined order?

Comment: The order was defined in my view? Wasn't aware of this.

Comment: [Putting `ORDER BY` in your view doesn't ensure any order, it just means that the `TOP` part of the view is evaluated correctly](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/08/23/sql-server-order-by-does-not-work-limitation-of-the-views-part-1/). `SELECT ... FROM x` If you don't ask for an order, you aren't guaranteed an order. It doesn't matter what `x` is.